# Facebook library for Xamarin.Android not updated for Android 12?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-12

I have an issue with my app.

It basically has the Xamarin.Facebook.Android library and I've noticed it is not updated to the last version available (the one that would fix the issue with Android 12 which makes the app crash when you complete the login process, because it misses important flags, MUTABLE and IMMUTABLE, necessary to use the SDK with Android 12+).
So I was wondering if there is any way to fix this problem and update the library, since the last stable version is the 11.2.0.1 which was released 1 year ago.

Thank you!

I've tried to update the library with NuGet Packages but with no avail. The last version available is old and isn't migrated to Android 12.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved on the facebook sdk version `'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:12.3.0'`, but the NuGet Package has not been upgraded.

This package belongs to Microsoft and Xamarin. So please wait for the package upgrade.

If you want to report it you can create a issue on the project:
[FacebookComponents](https://github.com/xamarin/FacebookComponents/issues)

**update**

These packages can provide a method to use the login function of the facebook. You can check this link : [Login with Facebook](https://github.com/xamarin/FacebookComponents/pull/237#issuecomment-1132175139)

Comment: Hello, thank you for the information!
Unfortunately I cannot afford to wait for God knows how long for Microsoft to update the library... I wanted to ask you is there another way to perform a login with Facebook using maybe an external browser instead on Android? At least until they decide to update the library

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT Obviously it *didn't* solve their problem, otherwise they wouldn't have followed up. If you can't answer, just say so. We're not on the MSFT forums here.